# How do i correctly put a $scope.$watch on a two dimensional array?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, watch

Putting an Angular watch on a multidimensional array is proving problematic

I have a screen where the user will see two teams (outer array) with a teamsheet(inner array) for each team. He is able to drag and drop the players to change the batting order.

The battingOrder is updated according to the player's spot in the array.

The following solution is a bit of a cop out/short term, but it does solve my immediate stumbling block.

**A more preferable solution would be appreciated though.**
The following code is in my controller.

```
    $scope.$watch(
        "Teams[0].TeamSheet",
        function (newValue, oldValue) {
            for (var i = 0; i < newValue.length; i++) {
                newValue[i].battingOrder = i + 1;
            }
        },
        true
    );

    $scope.$watch(
        "Teams[1].TeamSheet",
        function (newValue, oldValue) {
            for (var i = 0; i < newValue.length; i++) {
                newValue[i].battingOrder = i + 1;
            }
        },
        true
    );

    $scope.Teams = [{
        TeamName: "South-Africa",
        TeamSheet: [
        {
            name: "A Peterson",
            battingOrder: 1,
            mode: "view"
        },
        {
            name: "Riley Rossouw",
            battingOrder: 2,
            mode: "view"
        },
        {
            name: "H Amla",
            battingOrder: 3,
            mode: "view"
        },
        {
            name: "F Du Plessis",
            battingOrder: 4,
            mode: "view"
        },
        {
            name: "AB De Villiers",
            battingOrder: 5,
            mode: "view"
        }
        ]
    },

     {
         TeamName: "Australia",
         TeamSheet: [
         {
             name: "D Warner",
             battingOrder: 1,
             mode: "view"
         },
         {
             name: "S Watson",
             battingOrder: 2,
             mode: "view"
         },
         {
             name: "M Clarke",
             battingOrder: 3,
             mode: "view"
         },
         {
             name: "C Rogers",
             battingOrder: 4,
             mode: "view"
         },
         {
             name: "S Smith",
             battingOrder: 5,
             mode: "view"
         }
         ]
     }];
```

Comment: Use `$scope.$watchCollection` as per the doc https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope

Answer (score 0):

you can try to update batting order directly inside the view:

```
<div ng-repeat="member in team" ng-init="member.battingOrder = $index"> 
</div>
```

then you do not need to use $watch

**EDIT**

the previous solution will not work after you swap items in your array. Use the following code to overcome this problem:

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="member in team">
      {{setIndex(member,$index)}}
      {{member.name}},{{member.index}}
    </div>
    <button ng-click="swap()">swap first with last</button>
  </body>
```

controller:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.team = [ { index: 0, name : 'first' }, { index: 0, name : 'second' }, { index: 0, name : 'third' } ];
  $scope.swap = function () {
    var tmp = $scope.team[0];
    $scope.team[0] = $scope.team[2];
    $scope.team[2] = tmp;
  }

  $scope.setIndex = function (member, index)
  {
    member.index = index;
  }

});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/V3ixkww7dxcx8uZ7f0hj?p=preview